# In the case of a tie, how do I return the smaller number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, min

I need to write a function that takes two inputs, 'target' (integer) and 'values' (a list of integers), and find which number in 'values' is closest to 'target'. I came up with the following:

```
var targetNum = 0;
var valuesArr = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];

function closestToTarget(target, values) {
    var currVal = values[0];
    var diff = Math.abs(target - currVal);
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var currDiff = Math.abs(target - values[i]);
        if (currDiff < diff) {
            diff = currDiff;
            currVal = values[i];
        }
    }
    return currVal;
}
alert(closestToTarget(targetNum, valuesArr));
```

The function works, but I'm unable to return the smaller value in the case of a tie. The best that I could think of was the following which did not work:

```
function closestToTarget(target, values) {
    var currVal = values[0];
    var diff = Math.abs(target - currVal);
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var currDiff = Math.abs(target - values[i]);
        if (currDiff < diff) {
            diff = currDiff;
            currVal = values[i];
        }
        else if (currDiff == diff) {
            return Math.min[currVal, values[i]];
        }
        else {
            return currVal[i - 1];
        }
    }
    return currVal;
}
```

In the case of a tie, how do I return the smaller number in JavaScript?

Comment: well, `return Math.min[currVal, values[i]];` is a problem... use parens: `return Math.min(currVal, values[i]);`

Comment: As long as the values are sorted your first example seems to work just fine.

Comment: How do you have a smaller number in the case of a tie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea should work, but you could also use your first function but with the addition of something that checks for a lower tie at the end:

```
function closestToTarget(target, values) {
    var currVal = values[0];
    var diff = Math.abs(target - currVal);
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var currDiff = Math.abs(target - values[i]);
        if (currDiff < diff) {
            diff = currDiff;
            currVal = values[i];
        }
    }

    // We found the closest but now check if there's a smaller tie
    if (currVal > target && values.indexOf(target - diff) > -1 ) {
        return target - diff;
    }
    else {
    // if not just return what we originally found
        return currVal;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vsj0q5u9/2/

Comment: @JamesLawson Apologies, there were a couple of mistakes, now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like it would work try changing `Math.min[currVal, values[i]]` to `Math.min(currVal, values[i])` that should work if your values are ordered (simple syntax issue).

As kojow7 mentioned, the first function should also work as long as the `values` are ordered.

Otherwise instead of `return Math.min(...)` you should try to do `currVal = Math.min(...)` and keep iterating and then returning the `currVal` after the loop. This just makes sure that you check every value in the `values` array to make sure that you haven't missed anything (but if it's ordered, then there's no need to keep checking because the difference will only incraese).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the syntax error (missing parentheses) you could use some ES6 syntax to write a more concise function:

```js
function closestToTarget(target, values) {
    const m = Math.min(...values.map( v => Math.abs(target - v)));
    return Math.min(...values.filter( v => Math.abs(target - v) === m ));
}

var valuesArr = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
// Try several numbers
for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
    console.log(i, closestToTarget(i, valuesArr));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that when you find a new best difference, as well as recording the difference (`bestDiff`), you also record the value that caused that difference (`bestVal`).

So now, if you encounter a tie (`currDiff == bestDiff`), you need to check if it's a *better* tie, that is, check if the current value is smaller than the recorded one (`currVal < bestVal`). If it is, then we update the best values (update both `bestDiff` and `bestVal`).

```
function closestToTarget(target, values) {
    var currVal = values[0];
    var bestDiff = Math.abs(target - currVal);
    var bestVal = currVal;

    for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        var currVal = values[i];
        var currDiff = Math.abs(target - values[i]);
        if (currDiff < bestDiff || (currDiff == bestDiff && currVal < bestVal)) {
            bestDiff = currDiff;
            bestVal = currVal;
        }
    }
    return bestVal;
}
```

Examples:

```
closestToTarget(2,[2,4,6,8,10]) // 2
closestToTarget(2,[10,8,6,4,2]) // 2
closestToTarget(3,[10,8,6,4,2]) // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findClosest(inpt, ar) {
   var minDiff = Math.abs(ar[0] - inpt);
   var res = ar[0];
   for (var i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
       if(Math.abs((ar[i] - inpt)) < minDiff)
           res = ar[i];
   }
   return res;
}
```

This is simple example on how to get the closest value in the array for the given input.
There will be no lower number to return in case of a tie. if you have more than one closest integer in the array the difference between your input is the same for all the cases of a tie. so don't worry about it.